# How to change Preview Image on the Vista TaskBar?

Tags: wpf, windows-vista, taskbar

We have a window like this:

```
WPF main window (with glass border)
  -> Child window - frame control 
    -> Page
```

When user minimize the main window, and to view the preview image on Vista taskbar,
the preview image will display main window only, the child window (with that page) is missing.

So, my question is **how to fix this issue?**

Should I change the preview Image?

If yes, how?

Comment: Hey, I saw your question on Cold Fusion 4.5, I think I might be able to help you out on that if you explain further. I have no way to contact you, but let me know by commenting back on this thread, since they deleted your question, I had seen it then it was gone before I could reply!

Comment: Thanks Breadtruck, you can write to me, tata20011125 *at* gmail dot com, thanks very much.

Comment: @Cooper.Wu You should clarify if the question was answered (solution found). And if so, post the answer so others can learn something from it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - on mouseover at taskbar, a preview is generated. how can i achieve this by C# coding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484978/c-sharp-on-mouseover-at-taskbar-a-preview-is-generated-how-can-i-achieve-thi)

Comment: @BlackFrog That link shows how to enable the existing preview window, however I don't think it addresses setting the preview window to your own image.