# C# - on mouseover at taskbar, a preview is generated. how can i achieve this by C# coding

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, preview

I am developing a winForm application in which i am list all the running processes.
on mouseover of any process, i want preview window like (In Windows 7, when you mouse over an application in your task bar, a preview is generated showing the contents of the application window.)
See Image.

[image]

Any idea how to achieve this, i am not able to get it.
Any suggestion will be helpful.
Thanks..

Comment: This is a Windows 7 feature, isn't it?

Comment: Yup i want in window7.. but how can achieve this @KingKing

Comment: I'm not sure, I just wonder why it is a supported feature in Windows 7 but you still want to get it? Unless you want to deploy your application to use in a Windows XP system. Or you want to change the preview in the popup window arbitrarily?

Comment: I'm so confused. I see a giant Apple logo and the Snow Leopard background, but you're asking about a Windows application. Not sure if I can successfully overcome the cognitive dissonance to be able to answer the question.

Comment: @KingKing No i am developing an winform application where i am listing all the running processes. On mouseover on any process listed in my application i want the preview feature like in window 7. I hope now you will understand what actually i want.

Comment: @CodyGray Sry bro... this apple log is my wallpaper on window7. My operating system is window7 only. sry for confusion bro

Answer (score 8, accepted):

full example at this [**site**](http://villavu.com/forum/showthread.php?t=101448)
You need two functions :

```
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
static extern int DwmRegisterThumbnail(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, out IntPtr thumb);

[DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
static extern int DwmUpdateThumbnailProperties(IntPtr hThumb, ref DWM_THUMBNAIL_PROPERTIES props);
```

usage of DwmRegisterThumbnail
you are at your **form**, and **process** it a external program that you want to paint at your program.

```
IntPtr hWnd = process.MainWindowHandle;
int i = DwmRegisterThumbnail(this.Handle, hWnd, out thumb);
```

after registration, you just saying to windows the location to paint the picture

```
            DWM_THUMBNAIL_PROPERTIES props = new DWM_THUMBNAIL_PROPERTIES();

            props.fVisible = true;
            props.dwFlags = DWM_TNP_VISIBLE | DWM_TNP_RECTDESTINATION | DWM_TNP_OPACITY;
            props.opacity = 255;
            props.rcDestination = new Rect(panel.Left, panel.Top, panel.Right, panel.Bottom);

            DwmUpdateThumbnailProperties(thumb, ref props);
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to write any code to make this happen. It's part of the Aero theme, introduced with Windows Vista and still present in Windows 7. By default, a little thumbnail of the application's window is shown when you hover over its icon in the taskbar. That's true for the Skype example you showed, and also for a C# application that you write yourself.

If you want a finer level of control over exactly what gets shown in the preview (like if you only wanted to show a small portion of your app's window), you can write some code that calls one or more of the relevant [DWM API functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969527.aspx).

But don't write all of the P/Invoke code yourself. Use one of the existing libraries that wraps it all up in a .NET friendly way, like [Windows Forms Aero](http://windowsformsaero.codeplex.com/) or the [Windows API Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack).

Answer (score 0):

If you want your own application to display an Aero thumbnail, maybe [this C++ sample](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/05/13/10417964.aspx) could help you. Apparently it uses [DwmRegisterThumbnail()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to say "This HWND will now display a thumbnail of this other one".

So, a little P/Invoke call and `IWin32Window`...