# Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle returns zero

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, process

I'm trying to get the window handle (HWND) of the main form of my C# application (the application has only 1 form).

Some solutions on the internet show that I can use:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle
```

to get the window handle of current process of my application. But this value is always zero, anything wrong?

Comment: Just a side-note, looks like you don't have access to your form? why not just use `Handle` property?

Comment: If you only have 1 form use the handle property.

Comment: yeah, in the form, this.Handle gives a not-null pointer, but it doesn't seem correct coz when i try to access using that value, an access violation appears

Comment: How are you trying to use this handle that causes the access violation?

Comment: hm i got access violation when using the value returned by this.Handle with the dwm function DwmRegisterThumbnail

Comment: @PaulDinham: You can only access a form from the same thread it was created in (and where it's message loop runs in). That could be your problem. When (and where) are you calling DwnRegisterThumbnail?

Comment: @PaulDinham: Also, have a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484978/c-sharp-on-mouseover-at-taskbar-a-preview-is-generated-how-can-i-achieve-thi

Comment: @PaulDinham check your dllimport signature is using IntPtr you can't use int. http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/dwmapi.dwmregisterthumbnail.  Just mentioning this as you may get the same problem with the other handle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MSDN says:

> The main window is the window opened by the process that currently has the focus (the TopLevel form). You must use the Refresh method to refresh the Process object to get the current main window handle if it has changed.

and

> A process has a main window associated with it only if the process has a graphical interface. If the associated process does not have a main window, the MainWindowHandle value is zero. The value is also zero for processes that have been hidden, that is, processes that are not visible in the taskbar. This can be the case for processes that appear as icons in the notification area, at the far right of the taskbar.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In properties [F4] window '**Show in Taskbar**' should be **True**

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score -10):

try using

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle
```

Comment: @Ben Voigt :yes I know that but in my application it was considering "Process" class from some different namespace so I added System.Diagnostics and it worked.

Comment: But that would have been a compile time error.  It's not possible that this is the problem, when the question clearly says that code compiles and returns zero.