# Detect if external process is interactive and has any visible UI

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, process

I cannot seem to find a way to determine whether a `Process` has a user interface e.g. a window, which is visible to the user?

- [`Environment.UserInteractive`](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/UserInteractive.aspx) is not useful for external processes
- [`process.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) appears to always return false in my tests?

I would like to **differentiate between say Notepad and conhost**

Comment: There's no hard and fast rule to be able to determine whether a particular process has plans to open its first window in 5 seconds, 5 minutes, 5 weeks time. Or if it has some conditional logic that may or may not force interactivity to occur.

Comment: Incidentally, conhost may not be a good example, as it is responsible for presenting the console window.  So it has a message loop and so on, by most definitions it would be a GUI program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Find out the process ID from your `Process` instance.
2. Enumerate the top-level windows with `EnumWindows`.
3. Call `GetWindowThreadProcessId` and see if it matches the target PID.
4. Call `IsWindowVisible` and/or `IsIconic` to test if that window is visible to the user.

Comment: Might not work as desired, because IIRC GetWindowThreadProcessId() for a console window (sometimes?) returns a command-line process attached to that console.  And I assume console windows count as top-level windows in this context.  I'm not sure how best one would filter these out.

Comment: Haven't actually tested it, but hopefully these winapi calls work from a service

Comment: No they don't. Remember that a service runs in a different session from the interactive users' sessions. And sessions are isolated.

Answer (score 2):

The MSDN article about `System.Diagnostics.Process.MainWindowHandle` states the following

> If you have just started a process and want to use its main window handle, consider using the WaitForInputIdle method to allow the process to finish starting, ensuring that the main window handle has been created. Otherwise, an exception will be thrown.

What they are implying is that the `Window` might take several seconds to render after you've made the call for the `MainWindowHandle`, returning `IntPtr.Zero` even though you can clearly see a `Window` is shown.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle(v=vs.110).aspx for reference

Comment: In my case, the problem turned out that cannot use MainWindowHandle from service directly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370631/process-getcurrentprocess-mainwindowhandle-returns-zero

Answer (score 1):

Following @David Heffernan, this is what I did:

```cpp
HWND FindTopWindow(DWORD pid)
{
    std::pair<HWND, DWORD> params = { 0, pid };

    // Enumerate the windows using a lambda to process each window
    BOOL bResult = EnumWindows([](HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) -> BOOL
    {
        auto pParams = (std::pair<HWND, DWORD>*)(lParam);

        DWORD processId;
        if (GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &processId) && processId == pParams->second)
        {
            if (IsWindowVisible(hwnd)) {
                // Stop enumerating
                SetLastError(-1);
                pParams->first = hwnd;
                return FALSE;
            }

            return TRUE;
        }

        // Continue enumerating
        return TRUE;
    }, (LPARAM)&params);

    if (!bResult && GetLastError() == -1 && params.first)
    {
        return params.first;
    }

    return 0;
}
```