# Custom drawn thumbnail preview for window in taskbar

Tags: c#, wpf

By default, Windows shows the a thumbnail of the whole window as preview in the taskbar. I want to replace the default thumbnail by a custom drawn replacement. How can I do it?

I found [TaskbarItemInfo.ThumbnailClipMargin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.taskbariteminfo.thumbnailclipmargin(v=vs.110).aspx), but this property can only cut the thumbnail. I want to show a completely different content (in my  case some TextBlock controls). I'm using .NET 4.5 for my WPF application.

Comment: I think this may already have been discussed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484978/c-sharp-on-mouseover-at-taskbar-a-preview-is-generated-how-can-i-achieve-thi

Comment: I have read it, but don't really know how it could help me.

Comment: I assume this simply isn't possible. The window preview is a feature that windows as introduced and behaves as they want it to. Besides from a user standpoint I can't imagine a scenario where I would rather have an image displayed in the preview.

Comment: The most audio players do that. Actually I could finally find a solution also for my application :-) If anyone is interested, I can post it here.

Comment: @Martin What solution did you come up with?