# How to refresh taskbar preview even when the form is minimized

Tags: .net, vb.net, taskbar, windows-media-player, windows-api-code-pack

I'm having a problem and I noticed 90% of Windows(7,8,10) applications don't update taskbar preview (that little window when you hover over an app icon in taskbar) so when the app is minimized the taskbar preview just freezes and don't update besides some apps do update it even when minimized (e.g. Windows Media Player, Music Bee). I tried to fix this issue myself using `WindowsAPICodePack` and cropped the taskbar preview and I also used a second form and set the `Opacity` to 0 but it didn't work. I don't have any code to show right now.

Comment: [TaskbarItemInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.taskbariteminfo) or [DwmRegisterThumbnail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmregisterthumbnail) + [DwmUpdateThumbnailProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmupdatethumbnailproperties) + [DwmQueryThumbnailSourceSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmquerythumbnailsourcesize) + unregister the whole thing.

Comment: @Jimi It's been an hour and i'm trying to use DWMAPI.dll no luck i found a code from this post on SO (C# but i did convert it) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484978/c-sharp-on-mouseover-at-taskbar-a-preview-is-generated-how-can-i-achieve-thi) it just won't work, I tried everything to make it work, correct me if i'm wrong 'dest' is My App Handle, 'src' is the app that i'm trying to show, 'thumb' an integer to update the thumbnail 'DwmRegisterThumbnail' returns -2147024809,src is 0,Thumb is also 0 , here is my code https://pastebin.com/zGFjbQAu , Ref's https://pastebin.com/5KwEd1SE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To refresh the taskbar preview programmatically and use custom bitmaps:

```
    Imports System
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Taskbar

Namespace CustomThumbnailImage
    Public Partial Class Form1
        Inherits Form

        Private customThumbnail As TabbedThumbnail

        Public Sub New()
            InitializeComponent()
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnShown(ByVal e As EventArgs)
            MyBase.OnShown(e)
            customThumbnail = New TabbedThumbnail(Me.Handle, Me.Handle)
            TaskbarManager.Instance.TabbedThumbnail.AddThumbnailPreview(customThumbnail)
            customThumbnail.TabbedThumbnailBitmapRequested += AddressOf customThumbnail_TabbedThumbnailBitmapRequested
        End Sub

        Private Function GenerateBitmap() As Bitmap
            Dim bitmap As Bitmap = New Bitmap(150, 150)

            Using g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)
                Dim random = New Random(Environment.TickCount)

                Using brush = New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, random.[Next](255), random.[Next](255), random.[Next](255)))
                    g.FillEllipse(brush, 10, 30, 130, 90)
                End Using
            End Using

            Return bitmap
        End Function

        Private Sub customThumbnail_TabbedThumbnailBitmapRequested(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As TabbedThumbnailBitmapRequestedEventArgs)
            Dim bitmap = GenerateBitmap()
            customThumbnail.SetImage(bitmap)
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Sub(c)
                                             Thread.Sleep(2000)
                                             Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf InvalidateThumbnail))
                                         End Sub)
        End Sub

        Private Sub InvalidateThumbnail()
            customThumbnail.InvalidatePreview()
        End Sub
    End Class 
End Namespace
```

All part of the Win7Api Samples